# How do I write one template class instead of several ones?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, variadic-templates

There are several template classes that work with function pointers taking one, two, etc. arguments.

```
template <typename A1, int(*func)(A1)>
class Something1
{
public:
    static void f()
    {
        A1 a1;
        // ...
        int r = func(a1);
        // ...
    }
};

template <typename A1, typename A2, int(*func)(A1, A2)>
class Something2
{
public:
    static void f()
    {
        A1 a1;
        A2 a2;
        // ...
        int r = func(a1, a2);
        // ...
    }
};
```

How do I write one template class that can work with pointers to functions that take any number of arguments? Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot define a class template that has only one template parameter and accepts a function pointer the arguments of which must be deduced.
To do that, you have to use something like this:

```
template<typename F, F *func>
struct S;

template<typename R, typename... A, R(*f)(A...)>
struct S<R(A...), f> {};
```

And a pretty ugly notation like this one:

```
S<decltype(f), &f> s;
```

A possible alternative is by using the function pointer as an argument to the constructor:

```
#include<type_traits>
#include<utility>

template<typename>
struct S;

template<typename R, typename... A>
struct S<R(A...)> {
    S(R(*f)(A...)): f{f} {}
    R operator()(A... args) { return f(args...); }

private:
    R(*f)(A...);
};

void g() {}
int h(int) { return 0; }

int main() {
    S<void(void)> s1{&g};
    S<int(int)> s2{&h};
    s1();
    s2(42);
}
```

If you want to go a bit further and have a more flexible solution, you can work around it also by using lambdas and a factory method:

```
#include<type_traits>
#include<utility>

template<typename F>
struct S: F { S(F &&f): F{std::forward<F>(f)} {} };

template<typename F>
constexpr auto create(F &&f)
-> decltype(S<typename std::decay<F>::type>{std::forward<F>(f)}) {
    return S<typename std::decay<F>::type>{std::forward<F>(f)};
}

void g() {}
int h(int) { return 0; }

int main() {
    auto s1 = create([](){ g(); });
    auto s2 = create([](int i){ return h(i); });
    s1();
    s2(42);
}
```

---

As a side note, if you can use C++14, syntax of the last snippet becomes even nicer:

```
#include<type_traits>
#include<utility>

template<typename F>
struct S: F { S(F &&f): F{std::forward<F>(f)} {} };

template<typename F>
constexpr auto create(F &&f) {
    return S<std::decay_t<F>>{std::forward<F>(f)};
}

void g() {}
int h(int) { return 0; }

int main() {
    auto s1 = create([](){ g(); });
    auto s2 = create([](auto&&... args){ return h(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...); });
    s1();
    s2(42);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using class/struct template specialization, can be done something similar what you ask.

Instead of your `SomethingN` classes, I've developed the following `foo` struct; I've implemented a `bar()` method that receive a list of `Args...` to pass to `func` and a method `baz()` that receive nothing and create default constructed `Args...` values for `func`

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename F, F>
struct foo;

template <typename ... Args, int(*func)(Args...)>
struct foo<int(*)(Args...), func>
 {
   int bar (Args ... args)
    { return func(args...); }

   int baz ()
    { return func(Args{}...); }
 };


int func0 ()
 { return 0; }

int func1 (int)
 { return 1; }

int func2 (std::string const &, long)
 { return 2; }

int func3 (char, std::string const &, long)
 { return 3; }

int main ()
 {
   foo<decltype(&func0), func0>  f0;
   foo<decltype(&func1), func1>  f1;
   foo<decltype(&func2), func2>  f2;
   foo<decltype(&func3), func3>  f3;

   std::cout << f0.bar() << std::endl;                  // print 0
   std::cout << f1.bar(3) << std::endl;                 // print 1
   std::cout << f2.bar("string", 2L) << std::endl;      // print 2
   std::cout << f3.bar('c', "string", 2L) << std::endl; // print 3

   std::cout << f0.baz() << std::endl; // print 0
   std::cout << f1.baz() << std::endl; // print 1
   std::cout << f2.baz() << std::endl; // print 2
   std::cout << f3.baz() << std::endl; // print 3
 }
```

Comment: Personally, I would also conditionally supply a helper macro (only defined if some other macro, such as `ENABLE_MAKE_FOO`, is defined before the header is included), something like `#define make_foo(func_) foo<decltype(&func_), &func_>`, that can be used as `make_foo(func0) f0;` or `auto f0 = make_foo(func0){};`